# Setting DateTime format

Tags: c#, uwp

How do I set the format of my DateTime

> from: "27/5/2018"
>
> to: "27 May 2018"

and add a day infront.
Example : Sunday , 27 May 2018

I'm currently using `DateTime.Now` function but I want to change the format.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following ToString() format:

```
date.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");
```

- `dddd` will result in the full name of the day of the week
- `dd` will result in the day of the month
- `MMMM` will result in the full name of the month
- `yyyy` will result in the year as a four-digit number

If you want to learn more about date (time) formats, check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings).

Comment: I have another question. I successfully displayed my time as hh:mm:ss. I want to create a button where I click it and then the time shows and it runs automatically. how do I do that ?

Comment: @YannKang If you have another question, simply ask it here on Stack Overflow. Be sure that it is [an awesome question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

```
your_DateTime.ToString("dd/MMMM/yyyy");
```

---

***More Info :***

---

**`"d"`**

> The day of the month, from 1 through 31.
>   More information: The "d" Custom Format Specifier. Example :

*Example :* `2009-06-01T13:45:30 -> 1`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 15`

---

**`"dd"`**

> The day of the month, from 01 through 31.
>   More information: The "dd" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-01T13:45:30 -> 01`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 15`

---

**`"ddd"`**

> The abbreviated name of the day of the week.
>   More information: The "ddd" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> Mon (en-US)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> Пн (ru-RU)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> lun. (fr-FR)`

---

**`"dddd"`**

> The full name of the day of the week.
>   More information: The "dddd" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> Monday (en-US)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> понедельник (ru-RU)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> lundi (fr-FR)`

---

**`"f"`**

> The tenths of a second in a date and time value.
>   More information: The "f" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30.6170000 -> 6`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30.05 -> 0`

---

**`"ff"`**

> The hundredths of a second in a date and time value.
>   More information: The "ff" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30.6170000 -> 61`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0050000 -> 00`

---

**`"fff"`**

> The milliseconds in a date and time value.
>   More information: The "fff" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `6/15/2009 13:45:30.617 -> 617`, `6/15/2009 13:45:30.0005 -> 000`

---

**`"ffff"`**

> The ten thousandths of a second in a date and time value.
>   More information: The "ffff" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30.6175000 -> 6175`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000500 -> 0000`

---

**`"fffff"`**

> The hundred thousandths of a second in a date and time value.
>   More information: The "fffff" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30.6175400 -> 61754`, `6/15/2009 13:45:30.000005 -> 00000`

---

**`"ffffff"`**

> The millionths of a second in a date and time value.
>   More information: The "ffffff" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30.6175420 -> 617542`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000005 -> 000000`

---

**`"fffffff"`**

> The ten millionths of a second in a date and time value.
>   More information: The "fffffff" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30.6175425 -> 6175425`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0001150 -> 0001150`

---

**`"F"`**
If non-zero, the tenths of a second in a date and time value.

> More information: The "F" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30.6170000 -> 6`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0500000 -> (no output)`

---

**`"FF"`**
If non-zero, the hundredths of a second in a date and time value.

> More information: The "FF" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30.6170000 -> 61`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0050000 -> (no output)`

---

**`"FFF"`**
If non-zero, the milliseconds in a date and time value.

> More information: The "FFF" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30.6170000 -> 617`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0005000 -> (no output)`

---

**`"FFFF"`**
If non-zero, the ten thousandths of a second in a date and time value.

> More information: The "FFFF" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30.5275000 -> 5275`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000500 -> (no output)`

---

**`"FFFFF"`**
If non-zero, the hundred thousandths of a second in a date and time value.

> More information: The "FFFFF" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30.6175400 -> 61754`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000050 -> (no output)`

---

**`"FFFFFF"`**
If non-zero, the millionths of a second in a date and time value.

> More information: The "FFFFFF" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30.6175420 -> 617542`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0000005 -> (no output)`

---

**`"FFFFFFF"`**
If non-zero, the ten millionths of a second in a date and time value.

> More information: The "FFFFFFF" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30.6175425 -> 6175425`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30.0001150 -> 000115`

---

**`"g", "gg"`**

> The period or era.
>   More information: The "g" or "gg" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30.6170000 -> A.D.`

---

**`"h"`**

> The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 1 to 12.
>   More information: The "h" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T01:45:30 -> 1`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 1`

---

**`"hh"`**

> The hour, using a 12-hour clock from 01 to 12.
>   More information: The "hh" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T01:45:30 -> 01`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 01`

---

**`"H"`**

> The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 0 to 23.
>   More information: The "H" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T01:45:30 -> 1`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 13`

---

**`"HH"`**

> The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23.
>   More information: The "HH" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T01:45:30 -> 01`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 13`

---

**`"K"`**
Time zone information.

> More information: The "K" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* With DateTime values: `2009-06-15T13:45:30, Kind Unspecified ->`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30, Kind Utc -> Z`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30, Kind Local -> -07:00 (depends on local computer settings)`
With DateTimeOffset values: `2009-06-15T01:45:30-07:00 --> -07:00`, `2009-06-15T08:45:30+00:00 --> +00:00`

---

**`"m"`**

> The minute, from 0 through 59.
>   More information: The "m" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T01:09:30 -> 9`, `2009-06-15T13:29:30 -> 29`

---

**`"mm"`**

> The minute, from 00 through 59.
>   More information: The "mm" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T01:09:30 -> 09`, `2009-06-15T01:45:30 -> 45`

---

**`"M"`**

> The month, from 1 through 12.
>   More information: The "M" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 6`

---

**`"MM"`**

> The month, from 01 through 12.
>
> More information: The "MM" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 06`

---

**`"MMM"`**

> The abbreviated name of the month.
>   More information: The "MMM" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> Jun (en-US)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> juin (fr-FR)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> Jun (zu-ZA)`

---

**`"MMMM"`**

> The full name of the month.
>   More information: The "MMMM" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> June (en-US)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> juni (da-DK)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> uJuni (zu-ZA)`

---

**`"s"`**

> The second, from 0 through 59.
>   More information: The "s" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:09 -> 9`

---

**`"ss"`**

> The second, from 00 through 59.
>   More information: The "ss" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:09 -> 09`

---

**`"t"`**

> The first character of the AM/PM designator.
>   More information: The "t" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> P (en-US)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 午 (ja-JP)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> (fr-FR)`

---

**`"tt"`**

> The AM/PM designator.
>   More information: The "tt" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> PM (en-US)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 午後 (ja-JP)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> (fr-FR)`

---

**`"y"`**

> The year, from 0 to 99.
>   More information: The "y" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `0001-01-01T00:00:00 -> 1`, `0900-01-01T00:00:00 -> 0`, `1900-01-01T00:00:00 -> 0`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 9`, `2019-06-15T13:45:30 -> 19`

---

**`"yy"`**

> The year, from 00 to 99.
>   More information: The "yy" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `0001-01-01T00:00:00 -> 01`, `0900-01-01T00:00:00 -> 00`, `1900-01-01T00:00:00 -> 00`, `2019-06-15T13:45:30 -> 19`

---

**`"yyy"`**

> The year, with a minimum of three digits.
>   More information: The "yyy" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `0001-01-01T00:00:00 -> 001`, `0900-01-01T00:00:00 -> 900`, `1900-01-01T00:00:00 -> 1900`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 2009`,

---

**`"yyyy"`**

> The year as a four-digit number.
>   More information: The "yyyy" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `0001-01-01T00:00:00 -> 0001`, `0900-01-01T00:00:00 -> 0900`, `1900-01-01T00:00:00 -> 1900`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 2009`,

---

**`"yyyyy"`**

> The year as a five-digit number.
>   More information: The "yyyyy" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `0001-01-01T00:00:00 -> 00001`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> 02009`

---

**`"z"`**
Hours offset from UTC, with no leading zeros.

> More information: The "z" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30-07:00 -> -7`

---

**`"zz"`**
Hours offset from UTC, with a leading zero for a single-digit value.

> More information: The "zz" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30-07:00 -> -07`

---

**`"zzz"`**
Hours and minutes offset from UTC.

> More information: The "zzz" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30-07:00 -> -07:00`

---

**`":"`**

> The time separator.
>   More information: The ":" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> : (en-US)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> . (it-IT)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> : (ja-JP)`

---

**`"/"`**

> The date separator.
>   More Information: The "/" Custom Format Specifier.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> / (en-US)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> - (ar-DZ)`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 -> . (tr-TR)`

---

**`"string"`**
'string'    Literal string delimiter.

> More information: Character literals.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30 ("arr:" h:m t) -> arr: 1:45 P`, `2009-06-15T13:45:30 ('arr:' h:m t) -> arr: 1:45 P`

---

**`%`**
Defines the following character as a custom format specifier.

> More information:Using Single Custom Format Specifiers.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30 (%h) -> 1`

---

`\` 
|The escape character.

> More information: Character literals and Using the Escape Character.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T13:45:30 (h \h) -> 1 h`

---

**`Any other character`**

> The character is copied to the result string unchanged.
>   More information: Character literals.

*Example :* `2009-06-15T01:45:30 (arr hh:mm t) -> arr 01:45 A`

---

Source here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings